# Simple automatic callibration between print and scan

Tags: calibration

It ought to be fairly simple to make a program that prints a test page on your printer, compares the file to a scan of the printed page, and makes a calibration profile from that.

This would calibrate your scanner to your printer (using this type of paper and this type of ink), but would of course neither calibrate your monitor to the print nor calibrate them to a public calibration standard.

Does such a beast exist?

Comment: This wouldn't actually work since you wouldn't know what systematic error your scanner makes.

Comment: @joojaa But would that not be incorporated in the calibration profile? If it is a systematic error then it should be possible to adjust for that - possibly with a restriction of the gamut.

Comment: No, you dont know how your calibration works since your system as it self is not calibrated. Higher end printer have this feature though, as they actually have a colorimeter built into them. (note a imaging device is not a colorimeter)

Comment: Also note that a colorimeter is not a expensive component just not present in most scanners.

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly simple if you don't use anything in beetwen.
So office scanners/printers have that. They print calibration page, which is then put on scanner and it calibrate set points. It's all done on assumption that A) paper in machine is unified B)toners/inks have certain standards and C) there is no additional jammer in beetwen.
 It also assume that every "check point" on the page is printed as desired in design process. So in the colors bars there is enough ink/toner to print 100% and 5% tint (can be machine diagnosed if not), that the gradient/protractor are printed with the best crispiness possible (can be diagnosed be operator if not).

If I remeber correctly something like that was a feature in the higher Epson equpiment. It worked slighly different as it printed a test page, then after scanning told user what colors need to be "upped/downed". And it used a premade page from Epson (requirng a certain Epson paper).